# Accidently deleted a hidden file

Tags: mac

I accidentally deleted the .localized file from my mac desktop and then emptied my trash. How to I recover it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did it make any problems to your system?

> The ".localized" files simply contain user language dependent data.
>   This allows the Finder to display localized folder and file names. A
>   good example of this is the "Applications" folder, which on the file
>   system is called "Applications" but magically appears to the user with
>   a localized name (e.g. "Applicazioni" in Italian).

To restore it:

1. Open the terminal

   1. Type `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`
   2. Type `killall Finder`
2. Open the finder and go to the *Desktop* folder
3. Start Time Machine
4. Use Time Machine for restoring the `.localized` file
5. Open the terminal

   1. Type `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE`
   2. Type `killall Finder`

Skip steps 1 and 5 if you already see the hidden files in Finder and you like it.

Comment: Its made no problems.  Does this mean when I reboot the system or when I log out and back into it?

Comment: @Marina Sorry, that wasn't true. See the edited answer.

Comment: I simply found the file in applications (the .localized file) and then right clicked scrolled down to Copy file. Then went to the desktop then right clicked and typed paste file and it showed it on my desktop.  Do you think that will do the trick?

Comment: @Marina The best solution is using Time Machine. I'm not sure that the content of you `.localized`file on the Desktop was the same of the one you have in the Application folder.

Comment: I don't have Time Machine set up for my Mac

Comment: @Marina Ok, so probably copy and paste is a solution. In my case both the `.localized` files (Desktop and Application folders) are empty. If this was also your case I don't see any problem.

Comment: Alright. it didn't act like it had anything in it so I figured it was okay.  :)

Answer (score 2):

**.localized** are *zero* bytes files stored in several folders as simple placeholders, which tells Finder that folders are "localizable". The '.localized' file indicates (*just by its presence*) that apps should display "localized" name for a given folder if one was defined.

Therefore to recover it you may simply find '.localized' file in any other location and copy it to your desktop. Simplest case may be to issue the following command in a terminal window:

```
cp /Users/.localized /Users/{Your User Name Here}/Desktop/
```

Comment: Or even just `touch ~/Desktop/.localized`